# Do recovery partitions that don't have drive number belong to Ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive

I want to resize my Ubuntu disk space (from 20GB to 60GB).
Currently, I got Ubuntu alongside my Windows 8.1

What I want to do is I want to delete disk that contains Ubuntu altogether and reinstall it.
I was informed that Windows unable to read ext4 file system, thus on disk management, disks with no drive label belong to Ubuntu, here's a view of disk management from Windows

[image: Windows disk management] 
[image: Ubuntu GParted]

1. Is it safe to delete all these four? including the (recovery partition)
2. Does Ubuntu also have recovery partitions why each of them (recovery and primary) has 20GB?, when installing Ubuntu I only allocate 20GB for Ubuntu?
3. I also notice no "linux-swap" is it normal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) No. You lack enough confirmed information yet. Boot from a LiveUSB and look at the disk in GParted. It will confirm if the partitions really are available for an Ubuntu install.

2) Ubuntu does NOT have a recovery partition. It doesn't need one -- that's what the LiveUSB does. All of Ubuntu, including /home data storage, can be in a single, simple partition (or as complex across multiple partitions as you wish). Once you determine which partitions are available, you can decide upon how you want the partitions to be organized.

3) Yes, that's normal. 18.04 and newer Ubuntu installers will create a swap *file* instead of a separate *partition*. Swap partitions are useful for hibernation, but swap files allow better use of disk space.

Comment: hey thanks for answering, I edit my question with ss of GParted from Ubuntu, should I boot from LiveUSB instead or is it enough?

Comment: It's enough. Note that only two partitions (instead of four) seem available for the reinstall: sda7 and (optionally) sda8. Most folks install a separate /home (sda8) specifically to keep their data across precisely this kind of reinstall.

Comment: thanks for answering, more question
1. I am using Ubuntu 16.04 so I bet this doesn't have swap partition as well? How to know allocated size for this file?
2. Instead of resintalling can I expand my sda8 size using GParted while in Ubuntu? like [this tutorial](https://askubuntu.com/a/18525/1040815) @user535733

Comment: 1. Swapfiles are *files*, and can grow or shrink at need. 2. Yes, of course.